# RxJava - When and why to use Observable.share()

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I've seen patterns like this:

```
Observable<String> nameChanges = nameDataSource.changes().share();

// One subscriber
autoUnsubscribe(nameChanges.subscribe(() -> { ... }));

// Another subscriber
autoUnsubscribe(nameChanges.map(...).filter(...).subscribe(...));

// autoUnsubscribe is called when the UI is torn down
```

My question is:

*Why is it necessary to call `share()` whenever I want to listen to the Observable in multiple places?*

---

Why is not `share()` the default behavior for all observables?

It would be nice if the code above worked the same even without `.share()`. I would not have to think about when I need to share an Observable, and when I don't.

Is it for performance reasons because having a single subscriber is a special case that can be handled more efficiently?

From the docs this is not clear to me:

> share() returns a new ObservableSource that multicasts (shares) the original ObservableSource. As long there is at least one Observer this ObservableSource will be subscribed and emitting data.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are two kinds of `Observable`s: cold and hot. **Cold** `Observable`s start producing items when there is an `Observer` to them and they do it on an individual basis. Subscribing with multiple `Observer`s will result in multiple runs of the same cold `Observable`. An example of this is an `Observable` that issues a network request.

In contrast, a **hot** `Observable` can produce items with or without the presence of `Observer`s. These `Observable`s usually multicast the same items to all of their current `Observer`s. An example of this is an `Observable` of button clicks.

To turn a cold `Observable` into a hot one, you can use `publish()` which will make sure only a single subscription is established to the source `Observable` no matter how many `Observer`s there are. Thus, the chain will now act as a hot multicasting `Observable` from the `Observer`s' perspective.

However, often it is not economic to keep an originally cold `Observable` running after all `Observer`s of `publish()` have gone away, therefore the `refCount()` operator can be used to keep track of them and stop the source when there are no interesting parties left.

If your source is already hot, you don't need `share()`.

> Why is not share() the default behavior for all observables?

Actually, this property is one of the important contributions of the modern reactive programming paradigm: the distinction of the hot and cold `Observable`s.

However, multicasting is expensive on itself because you have to keep track of the set of current `Observer`s in order to notify them with new events, and this can lead to all sorts of logical race conditions to be defended against. A cold `Observable` is known to talk only to a single `Observer` so there is no need for the extra tracking overhead.

Comment: For some Observables in our codebase, I don't actually know whether they are hot or cold. For example:

Observable<Account> accountChanges = accountStorage.account();

I want to add two subscribers, but I don't know whether accountChanges is hot or cold, so I don't know if I need share(). I think it's a hot observable but is there an easy way to tell?

Comment: You can't tell, but you should ask the question why would it be a hot source and whether or not the author should indicate this via documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`I would not have to think about when I need to share an Observable, and when I don't.` I'm afraid that you will have to think when programming. ;)

In the above code, yes, sharing makes sense. But what if you we're updating something on the backend, using the same network and method call from two different points, updating with different data? You would have the same call with the same Observable, but you certainly *wouldn't* want to share the Observable instance (and the network call) because that means that all successive calls with data would be discarded in the favour of the first one. Or if you wanted to start a timer whenever you're subscribed, you again wouldn't want to share this with other Observables.

Also, it is much easier to *add* certain behaviour than to *remove* it. For example, if sharing was the default, and the second subscriber wouldn't want to share and removes the sharing - what about the third one? Will it share it with the first one or not? At that point the sharing property becomes the property of the `Subscriber` and not the `Observable` and you would have no clear way of knowing which one is shared and which one isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! In API design it's a good thing to make users think only as much as is necessary. So if there was a way to remove share() from the API, the API would be easier to use. See also my comment on the answer above about the distinction between hot and cold observables being not obvious to a newcomer.