# Cold observable that will emit only once, even when second subscription will be made

Tags: android, rx-java, android-lifecycle

I have RxJava - Android - Lifecycle problem. 
I'm developing app using MVI architecture and my middleware layer is binding to intents which are basically observables from the view (Activity/Fragment)

Subscription to this intents happens in Activities onStart method (this is quite important)
Let's assume I want to have an Intent (Observable source) which will emit only once during the first Subscription (so it has to be cold observable)
but never more, so when user blocks his phone and onStart will be called again and middleware will resubscribe to this observable NO item will be emitted.

This would be a perfect case for a subjects or Observable.just but the case for possible multiple onStart ruins everything. 
Would be grateful for any ideas/hints.

Comment: I think `share` might be useful here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460553/rxjava-when-and-why-to-use-observable-share